# Caching rendered pages of database queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Whats the best approach for caching search results on a site so that a user can still use the back button?

The results are pulled from a database query (Laravel & Eloquent) performed using a post request. These are rendered using Blade templates, but when a user clicks on a result, then clicks back I get a

`Confirm Form Resubmission`

`This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.`

I know if I used the url to pass the variables in the search I would be fine, but is there another way?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Confirm Form Resubmission` prevents the from to post the data again. There are always more steps. 1. The server send the form to the client. 2. User submit the form 3. Server handles the form and mostly redirects to an result page. If user now hits BACK he will not jump to 1. He will resend the form! And that should not be done and is fairly blocked by the browser.

Comment: You can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks Taha, I've read and thats how I implement when its a static page. but the page isn't static, the results will always be different. 

I'm guessing it might be easier to just use the url to pass along the variables